# I'd like to pick 1 column of MySQL table rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a made a MySQL table, and I've been trying to make it answer on my site. As for now, it picks all the columns in my rows, and I wanted to pick a specific column.

Does anyone know a better way to make it echo on your page?

```
<?php
$data = "SELECT * FROM anmeldelser";

$result = $connection->query($data);



while($row = $result->fetch_array()){

    echo "<b>Kundenavn:&nbsp;</b>" . $row['Kundenavn'] . "<b>&nbsp;Kommentar:&nbsp;</b>" . $row['Kommentar'] . "<b>&nbsp;Dato:&nbsp;</b>" . $row['Dato'];

}

?>`
```

This gives the result of every row in my db. I want to pick one random or just be specific about which one I want to place in which div.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your query in `$data` ?

Comment: you can fix it in you query $data by putting a query that return one row or you can remove the while loop to see the first row

Comment: You should start reading some basic introduction into sql. Such "getting started guides" are really easy to understand, give you examples and explanations and will help you to understand what you are doing. That way you will be much faster in coding then when trying around as you currently do. Really, it is worth investing that time. Have fun!

Comment: $data = "SELECT * FROM mytabel WHERE name = 'Steve'";

Comment: and it was
$data = "SELECT * FROM mytabel";

Comment: Thanks for the replies and tips guys! arkascha, you are right. I'm just felt to confident about this exam - but i got stuck, and now i'm on my way forward again. :) But thanks - i'll do some more research next time.

Answer (score -3):

i found a solution myself.

```
$data = "SELECT * FROM mytabel WHERE name = 'Steve'";
```

To select the next, you copy the line and type the next name of your tabel.

```
$data = "SELECT * FROM mytabel WHERE name = 'Bob'";
```

Which makes it echo only one of the columns.